# Standard output format using a variable

Tags: fortran, fortran90

In Fortran90 I would like to set the format of an output using a variable. My code looks like this:

```
fileUnit = 14
myFormat = '(10e18.10)' 
write (fileUnit,myFormat) myData
```

The value of `myFormat` can be any allowed for the type of `myData`. Is there a way to set `myFormat` such that the output is equivalent to coding

```
write (fileUnit,*) myData
```

Comment: You want a format equivalent to the `*`? There isn't any. But perhaps I don't understand your question. What does the sentence *The value of myFormat can be any allowed for the type of myData.* mean?

Comment: I'm sure you know but it should be `myFormat = '(10e18.10)'`

Comment: @VladimirF: Yes, I am basically looking for a format equivalent to the `*`. The sentence you highlighted just means that I'd like `myData` to be of any data type for which a standard output is defined.

Comment: @agentp: sure, thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a bare `*` in an explicit format specification like you can in a `read` or `write` statement.  In the explicit format context, `*` represents an *unlimited-format-item* group that gives an infinite repeat count to a group of *format-items* rather than representing list directed formatting (see Cl. 9.6.2.2, R915, Fortran 2008).

The character variable holding your explicit format can be constructed at run-time, so your option to handle dynamic needs is to write code to determine the proper format specification based upon your data.  Depending on your compiler, and if your data is a derived type, you may also have the option of defined output (See Cl. 9.6.4.8.3 Fortran 2008) to handle your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically switch between explicit and list directed format you could do something like this:

```
 if(myFormat.eq.'*')then
      write(unit,*)...
 else
      write(unit,myFormat)...
 end if
```